# React/Redux: State is updated in Redux object, but React component doesn't re-render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Tried to look through similar questions, but didn't find similar issues.

I am trying to implement sorts by name and amount in my app, this event is triggered in this component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { sortByExpenseName, sortByExpenseAmount } from '../actions/expensesFilters';

class ExpensesListFilter extends Component {
  onSortByExpenseName = () => {
    this.props.sortByExpenseName();
  };

  onSortByExpenseAmount = () => {
    this.props.sortByExpenseAmount();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>Expense Name</span>
        <button onClick={this.onSortByExpenseName}>Sort me by name</button>
        <button onClick={this.onSortByExpenseAmount}>Sort me by amount</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
  sortByExpenseName: () => dispatch(sortByExpenseName()),
  sortByExpenseAmount: () => dispatch(sortByExpenseAmount()),
});

export default connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(ExpensesListFilter);
```

for that I am using following selector:

```js
export default (expenses, { sortBy }) => {
  return expenses.sort((a, b) => {
    if (sortBy === 'name') {
      return a.name < b.name ? 1 : -1;
    } else if (sortBy === 'amount') {
      return parseInt(a.amount, 10) < parseInt(b.amount, 10) ? 1 : -1;
    }
  });
};
```

I run this selector in mapStateToProps function for my ExpensesList component here:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ExpensesItem from './ExpensesItem';

// my selector
import sortExpenses from '../selectors/sortExpenses';


const ExpensesList = props => (
  <div className="content-container">
    {props.expenses && props.expenses.map((expense) => {
        return <ExpensesItem key={expense.id} {...expense} />;
    }) }
  </div>
);

// Here I run my selector to sort expenses
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    expenses: sortExpenses(state.expensesData.expenses, state.expensesFilters),
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ExpensesList);
```

This selector updates my filter reducer, which causes my app state to update:

```js
import { SORT_BY_EXPENSE_NAME, SORT_BY_EXPENSE_AMOUNT } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_EXPENSE_FILTER_STATE = {
  sortBy: 'name',
};

export default (state = INITIAL_EXPENSE_FILTER_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SORT_BY_EXPENSE_NAME:
      return {
        ...state,
        sortBy: 'name',
      };
    case SORT_BY_EXPENSE_AMOUNT:
      return {
        ...state,
        sortBy: 'amount',
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Sort event causes my state to update, the expenses array in my expenses reducer below is updated and sorted by selector, BUT the ExpensesList component doesn't re-render after my expenses array in state is updated.
What I want my ExpensesList component to do, is to re-render with sorted expenses array and sort ExpensesItem components in list.
What could be the reason why it fails? Pretty sure I am missing out something essential, but can't figure out what. My expenses reducer:

```js
import { FETCH_EXPENSES } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_EXPENSES:
      return {
        ...state,
        expenses: action.expenses.data,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

All these components are childs to this parent component:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ExpensesListFilter from './ExpensesListFilter';
import ExpensesList from './ExpensesList';

const MainPage = () => (
  <div className="box-layout">
    <div className="box-layout__box">
      <ExpensesListFilter />
      <ExpensesList />
    </div>
  </div>
);

export default MainPage;
```

App.js file (where I run startExpenseFetch)

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import 'normalize.css/normalize.css';

import AppRouter, { history } from './routers/AppRouter';
import configureStore from './store/configureStore';
import LoadingPage from './components/LoadingPage';
import { startExpenseFetch } from './actions/expensesData';
import './styles/styles.scss';

const store = configureStore();

const jsx = (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRouter />
  </Provider>
);

let hasRendered = false;

const renderApp = () => {
  if (!hasRendered) {
    ReactDOM.render(jsx, document.getElementById('app'));
    hasRendered = true;
  }
};

store.dispatch(startExpenseFetch()).then(() => {
  renderApp();
});

ReactDOM.render(<LoadingPage />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Rest of files:

ExpenseItem Component:

```js
import React from 'react';

const ExpenseItem = ({ amount, name }) => (
  <div>
    <span>{name}</span>
    <span>{amount}</span>
  </div>
);

export default ExpenseItem;
```

Action creators:

expensesData.js

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import { FETCH_EXPENSE } from './types';

// no errors here
const ROOT_URL = '';

export const fetchExpenseData = expenses => ({
  type: FETCH_EXPENSE,
  expenses,
});

export const startExpenseFetch = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    return axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `${ROOT_URL}`,
    })
      .then((response) => {
        dispatch(fetchExpenseData(response));
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
};
```

expensesFilters.js

```js
import { SORT_BY_EXPENSE_NAME, SORT_BY_EXPENSE_AMOUNT } from './types';

export const sortByExpenseName = () => ({
  type: SORT_BY_EXPENSE_NAME,
});

export const sortByExpenseAmount = () => ({
  type: SORT_BY_EXPENSE_AMOUNT,
});
```

configureStores.js file

```js
import { createStore, combineReducers, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import expensesDataReducer from '../reducers/expensesData';
import expensesFilterReducer from '../reducers/expensesFilters';

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

export default () => {
  const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
      expensesData: expensesDataReducer,
      expensesFilters: expensesFilterReducer,
    }),
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk))
  );
  return store;
};
```

AppRouter.js file

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Router, Route, Switch, Link, NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import MainPage from '../components/MainPage';
import NotFoundPage from '../components/NotFoundPage';

export const history = createHistory();

const AppRouter = () => (
  <Router history={history}>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" component={MainPage} exact={true} />
        <Route component={NotFoundPage} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
);

export default AppRouter;
```

Comment: Is your ExpansesList a parent component? If not in which parent component it’s being called?

Comment: @HemadriDasari ExpansesList  is a parent component for ExpensesItem, the selector is run in this component. There also is a top parent component for ExpensesList too:

Comment: @HemadriDasari will update it in question now

Comment: I don't see where you use `rates` in `ExpensesList` which you map it to `props`. Should it cause the problem?

Comment: Ok. To Fetch expenses you will be calling an action call. Where is it? I see your ExpensesList is checking for expenses props so I want to know wr this fetch expenses action call is fired. I guess it should be in your parent component of ExpensesList. If so please post that code where the fetch expenses action call is fired.

Comment: @TuấnTrầnDuy oh no no, it is correct in original code, my bad of not  correcting it here

Comment: @HemadriDasari I am calling it in app.js file, before app runs. Will add it to question now too

Comment: @HemadriDasari I did add the file, I see what error I had with passing expenses as props in MainPage component, I did fix it, but still doesn't work. I will update the component in question for I have fixed it to

Comment: @KaterinaBezlepkina I think you should consider to replace `const ExpensesList` by `class`

Comment: The issue I could see is You are returning new sorted props expenses in ExpensesList but we not using it anywhere. Though you return sorted expenses as props in your ExpensesList component it won’t re-render because ExpensesList is being called in Parent and you passing sorted expenses props in ExpensesList. You have to send sorted expenses from parent component to ExpensesList component to make it re-render I guess or it’s better if you can change ExpensesList to class instead of functional component. then you can play with in ExpensesList component using componentWillReceiveProps

Comment: @HemadriDasari was thinking about that too.
 I am reusing this method of sorting list from the course I used to go through before, it did work in other app I made with course, but I am missing something in this app, pretty much sure something simple and essential. If I won't be able to fix, maybe I will try to change it class instead. Thanks for the tips!

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have a typo on your call to your selector? :)

```
// Here I run my selector to sort expenses
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    expenses: sortExpenses(state.expensesData.expenses, state.expnsesFilters),
  };
};
```

**state.expnsesFilters** look like it should be state.**expenses**Filters

Which is one of the reasons you should make your `sortExpenses` selector grab itself the parts of the state it needs and do it's job on its own. You could test it isolation and avoid mistakes like this.

Comment: Oh no, it is fine in original code, just me copying here with typo. It actually runs and sorts everything ok on first render. But when I click on sorting button, vue layer doesn't re-render. Need to dig in it again, pretty sure some stupid error from my side with something essential. Thanks for the tip :)

Answer (score 0):

I found a reason why it happens, in my selector I was mutating my app's state. I wasn't returning a new array from it, and was changing the old one instead, that didn't trigger my vue layer to re-render. Fixed it and it works now.